# list modification in python without iteration

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list like this-:

```
 list= [[Timestamp('2019-02-08 19:00:00'), -0.10272366503382457],
[Timestamp('2019-02-08 20:00:00'), -0.09879936173003045],
[Timestamp('2019-02-08 21:00:00'), -0.09485899037087542],
[Timestamp('2019-02-08 22:00:00'), -0.09090362376394268],
[Timestamp('2019-02-08 23:00:00'), -0.08693431127731444],
[Timestamp('2019-02-09 00:00:00'), -0.08295207923696779]....]
```

I want to filter it and get a output like this-:

```
  ['2019-02-08 19:00:00', -0.10272366503382457],
  ['2019-02-08 20:00:00', -0.09879936173003045],
  ['2019-02-08 21:00:00', -0.09485899037087542],
  ['2019-02-08 22:00:00', -0.09090362376394268],
  ['2019-02-08 23:00:00', -0.08693431127731444],
  ['2019-02-09 00:00:00', -0.08295207923696779].....,
```

i use this `str(list_result[0][0])` syntax , but problem is I have to

iterate all lists which is time consuming .

is it possible with iteration ?

thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with how you mean to filter your list. Your question seems to show the same number of items and thus there was no filtering.

Comment: ok , let me modify it,   @quamrana

Comment: @arjun kindly check the answer provided below, and let me know if that helps...

Comment: i am just working on it @DevanshuMisra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to help you format your datetime object and then append them in the list like you did at first.

E.g.,

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

will yield:

```
'02/23/2012'
```

More information about formatting see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

This will only help you in converting the datetime object to string and will not filter out anything. Also, since **Lists** are Python's representation of arrays and fetching it's elements is not possible without iteration or indexing.

Comment: hey, thanks for your time , I just update my question , the solution you have provided is good but i will not use it coz if i will apply it dynamically i have to iterate the loop , can you suggest something else?

Comment: i am going to post one more question , just help me out

Comment: @arjun I'd ask you to put your code, which you find problematic, in the question so that the community could help you accordingly. It's not possible for us to provide you with a solution that does not use iteration without actually knowing as to when and where it is being implemented. If you post your code in the question we'd be able to provide you with a better solution.

Comment: @arjun I think that there is going to have to be iteration... somewhere.

Comment: @quamrana that is exactly what I'm trying to tell our friend here, since you cannot extract the elements from a list without iteration. Or you'll have to use indexing, but that is not possible in a dynamically populated list (Unless you are sure of the element's position in the list).